# interact with SVG Marker element with event handlers in React(JS)

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, dom-events

see demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-marker-element-ekkkx?file=/src/App.js
as you can see - the events on the `marker` element just do not fire.

what can do to make it work, or any idea for an easy alternative implementing arrowhead without the use of SVG marker elements, or any sort of workaround?

(you can see a more detailed explanation of the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61918626/reactjs-is-it-currently-possible-to-fire-event-on-a-url-referenced-marker-svg/61923269#61923269) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to reposition the arrow using `translate`, so that the `marker` element would no longer be needed. Here's the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-marker-element-ewp6g?file=/src/App.js

Another option is to create a transparent absolute positioned element layered on top of the arrow's head: https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-marker-element-uf3sz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: great suggestion friend, but not working with Marker element and using this method will make my life much harder. this is only a simplified example, [see the real usage](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/Eliav2/react-xarrows/tree/master/examples?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), using this method will force me to calculate the angel my self.

Comment: I've added another idea using `position: absolute`

Comment: nice suggestion and thanks for the advice - but this event is fired when hovering on the div -  but the div takes shape of the rectangle and not the shape of the arrow. see by adding `backgroud:"black solid 1px"` attribute .

Comment: I don't know how to get rid of that @EliavLouski. Even if you mapped `mousemove` events to X,Y coordinates to infer intersection, you'll still need to know the angles to deduce the arrow's perimeter.

Comment: maybe you right and i need to implement the behavior of marker element by my self using g element. thanks for the advice - i will take a look and will work on it to implement it when i will have time

Comment: thank you friend. I implemented the features of marker i needed element in a `g` element and it works perfectly.